# HMR busted with webpack4

Tags: reactjs, webpack, webpack-hmr, react-hot-loader

Im at wits end with this issue in my upgrade to webpack 4 no matter what i do HMR never see's any changes here are the relevant files

I'm aware the loadAsyncComponent is not compatable with HMR im attempting to hot reload root.js at the moment then fix from there once i get it working at all...

this is the HMR version 4

https://gist.github.com/th3fallen/ee81e2533f4f847ac9873ad49b8c5557

I also have a config in HMR 3 which was the previous working version that i've prefixed the filename as v3 in the gist

Answer (score 0, accepted):

apparently the issue was with webpack-dev-server not working with ip's